# plotting two numeric variables in the same graph

Tags: r

I want to visualise two variables in the same graph.

the variables look like this

```
> head(intp.trust_male)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  average_intp.trust
               <dbl>
1               2.33
```

and

```
> head(intp.trust_fem)
# A tibble: 1 × 1
  average_intp.trust
               <dbl>
1               2.34
```

I have tried merge to put them in the same data frame, but it doesn't seem to work

```
Q5 <- merge(intp.trust_fem, intp.trust_male)

ggplot(data = Q5)+
  aes(fill = percent_owned) + 
  geom_sf()  + 
  scale_fill_viridis_c()
```

can anyone help me out here, please?
Thank you :)

Comment: Please provide more details: what graph are you trying to get? What do you mean "it doesn't seem to work"? Do you get an error? Do you get a graph that is not what you want? Your ggplot code looks wrong, `aes` should go within either the `ggplot` or the `geom_sf` functions, but that may or may not be the only problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is stack your data frames. You can do this with `dplyr::bind_rows`. It's not clear from your question what you're trying to accomplish because `percent_owned` is not a variable in the data you've shown. Generally, you could do (using `geom_point`):

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

intp.trust_male <- mutate(intp.trust_male, label = "intp.trust_male")
intp.trust_fem <- mutate(intp.trust_fem, label = "intp.trust_fem")

df <- bind_rows(intp.trust_male, intp.trust_fem)

ggplot(df, aes(x = label, y = average_intp.trust)) + 
  geom_point()
```

Comment: Hi, the codes run ok, but the graph is not what I expected.